# How to group elements of a vector by a pattern?

Tags: rust, iterator

How to break a vector such as `[9,7,6,3,4,0,1,7,3,9]` -> `[[9,7,6,3],[4,1],[7,3],[9]]` -> `[25,5,10,9]`?

The logic behind it is that a vector is broken into subvectors where each subsequent element is smaller than previous one(0'z are ignored), a descending sequence . When the subvectors are formed, each one is replaced with a sum of all of its elements.

[https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f8fb3c06c8f520032c1e091][1]

Comment: Given that this is a codewars problem, what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Here is a question solving a similar problem requiring grouping sequences of a vec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380352/how-can-i-group-consecutive-integers-in-a-vector-in-rust

Comment: I'm trying to solve the kata without converting the original 2d matrix from row-major-order to column-major-order.  I was thinking about either windows()+cmp_by()  or group_by() but cant get my head aroud to come up with a solution for it https://github.com/radionnazmiev/blobservation_2_merge_inert_blobs/blob/master/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the elements of the `nums` to build up the split. For every number, compare it to the last number to decide whether to create a sublist, or append to the existing one:

```rust
let nums = vec![9,7,6,3,4,0,1,7,3,9];
let mut split: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![]];
for num in nums.iter().filter(|n| **n != 0) {
    let sublist = split.last_mut().unwrap();
    match sublist.last_mut() {
        Some(x) if num > x => {
            split.push(vec![*num]);
        }
        _ => sublist.push(*num),
    }
}
let split = split; // make split immmutable
let summed: Vec<i32> = split.iter().map(|v| v.iter().sum()).collect();
```

([try in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81f92bc4a3dd4a27c7db178a7c8b60aa))

It's probably possible to make a more elegant solution using [`Iterator::partition_in_place`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition_in_place), but that `fn` is sadly unstable for now.

Comment: I was looking for the functional version of it, but it will do as well. Greatly appreciate your effort 